# How to use kivy spinner value

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a spinner widget, along with a button widget. When the button is clicked, I want the selected spinner value to be saved in a dictionary within a different file.

I've successfully done this with the TextInput widget by using self.text

But with the spinner, I cannot find the selected value.

In my kv file, the spinner looks like

```
     Spinner:
         id: trans_que
         text: "Transport Ques"
         values: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

In my python file, I have

```
    a_1["account_1"]["transportque"] = self.trans_que.values
```

as an attempt to save the selected spinner value, but I receive an attribute error.

So my question is, when a user selects a value from the spinner widget and clicks the button, how can I call that value?

Comment: The `text` property of the `Spinner` holds the current selection.

Comment: @JohnAnderson i tried self.trans_que.text. It also gives me an error

Comment: Try `self.ids.trans_que.text`.

Comment: @JeromeEscalante wow... this worked. no idea why. thanks. i will look into what ids is